# Should I ask a theme developer to use locate_template rather than require_once

Tags: functions, child-theme, parent-theme

I was creating a child theme today and needed to overwrite a php file which was included using this code in the themes functions.php file

`require_once( get_template_directory() . '/function-includes/theme-functions.php' );`

I tried using `require_once( get_stylesheet_directory(). '/function-includes/theme-functions.php' );` in my child themes functions file but it caused an error and didn't load the site at all.

So I ended up using `locate_template( '/function-includes/theme-functions.php', true );` in the parent themes functions.php file

Is `locate_template` a better method for theme developers to use to allow child theme development?

Is there an alternative way for me to use only my child themes functions.php to overwrite that theme-functions.php file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, Child Themes were originally intended to be able to do two things:

1. Override parent Theme CSS
2. Override parent Theme *template* files

I doubt that the Theme developer intends for the `/function-includes/theme-functions.php` file to be overridden by a Child Theme. Functional files are usually a core component of the Theme, and allowing a Child Theme to override them wholesale would introduce serious development complexity into the Theme.

Rather than ask for a functional file to be able to be overridden by a Child Theme, I would instead ask the developer to make custom function output *filterable*, or (where appropriate), to make some custom functions *pluggable* (by far, I prefer filterable function output to pluggable functions).

Comment: Thanks Chip that makes more sense to ask that they add filters and hooks into the theme.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to retrieve the `theme-functions.php` file located in the parent theme directory?

When you want to call a file from the parent theme directory you must use,

```
get_template_directory()
```

When you want to call a file from your child theme directory then you use,

```
get_stylesheet_directory()
```

Comment: No i'm trying to get the file from my child theme which is why I used get_stylesheet_directory() and it just displayed a white / blank page and nothing loaded at all.